# Unable to reach my .Net core application deployed on a linux server from web browser

Tags: .net, linux, .net-core, asp.net-core-7.0, centos7.6

I have the following in my appsettings.json

```
  "Kestrel": {
"EndPoints": {
  "Http": {
    "Url": "http://0.0.0.0:1000"
  },
  "Https": {
    "Url": "http://0.0.0.0:1001"
  }
 }
}
```

And when I publish the application and deploy it to the server. I run the following command

> dotnet run appname.dll

and I get the following message at the console on the server

[image]

But when I visit the IP address and port on the browser, i get the following

[image]

Please how can I resolve this to reach the application from the browser?

Comment: Are you using the correct URL with port? Is there a firewall running on the Linux machine with that port opened up for ingress?

Comment: @DavidG I am using the correct IP address and port but I'm not aware of any firewall on the port.

Comment: Are you trying to visit the application from the same machine as the server? If not, what happens when you do?

Comment: @Luke I am trying to reach the application from the browser over the internet. There is no browser on the server for me to try that on the same machine

Comment: In that case, I'm guessing that this is likely a firewall or a port forwarding issue. Have you forwarded ports 1000 and 1001 to your host machines local IP in your router configuration?